# How do I add a block to a matrix that already has content via a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development

I'm building a plugin that adds blocks to a matrix in an entry from the front end. I got it up and running by following the answer in this post:

[How to save a matrix content of a new entry in my plugin?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1101/how-to-save-a-matrix-content-of-a-new-entry-in-my-plugin/1218#1218)

How do I check if the matrix already has blocks when I fetch the entry? And then, once I know if the matrix already has blocks, how do I retain the existing data while saving new blocks via the plugin?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can save Matrix blocks directly, without having to re-save the entry.

### Craft 2

Use [MatrixService::saveBlock()](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v2/craft-matrixservice.html#method-saveblock):

```php
$block = new MatrixBlockModel();
$block->fieldId = 5;
$block->ownerId = 100;
$block->ownerLocale = 'en_us';
$block->typeId = 2;
$block->sortOrder = 10;

$block->setContentFromPost(array(
    'fieldHandle' => 'value',
    // ...
));

$success = craft()->matrix->saveBlock($block);
```

### Craft 3

Use [craft\services\Elements::saveElement()](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-elements.html#method-saveelement):

```php
use Craft;
use craft\elements\MatrixBlock;

$block = new MatrixBlock();
$block->fieldId = 5;
$block->ownerId = 100;
$block->siteId = 1;
$block->typeId = 2;
$block->sortOrder = 10;

$block->setFieldValues([
    'fieldHandle' => 'value',
    // ...
]);

$success = Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($block);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me.

Here's a gist that shows how this can be used to create a new entry if there isn't one for the block to be added to yet if anyone else needs to do this: https://gist.github.com/bwlng/5c0bdeff62fabe247c87

Would resaving the entry after adding all the blocks update the search keywords?

Comment: @StephenBowling Yes that’s a possibility. Just updated the code example showing how you could re-save the entry's content after saving the new matrix block.

Comment: @BrandonKelly how has this changed in Craft 3? I don't see a `MatrixBlockModel`.

Comment: @cmal just updated my answer for Craft 3.