# Saving related entry in a Matrix block programmaticially

Tags: plugin-development

I'm trying to add entries to a Matrix block with one field type of 'entry' using the following:

```
$block = new MatrixBlockModel();
$block->fieldId    = 9;             // Matrix field's ID
$block->ownerId    = $collectionID; // ID of entry the block should be added to
$block->typeId     = 2;             // ID of block type
$block->getContent()->setAttributes(array(
    'contentRss' => array($entry->id)
));

$success = craft()->matrix->saveBlock($block);
```

The code saves the new block and entry, but when I view the entry it has not linked the entry. I notice in the database tables it has not created an entry in the `craft_relations` table.

Where am I going wrong? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possibly a duplicate of [this one here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1101/how-to-save-a-matrix-content-of-a-new-entry-in-my-plugin/1218) but hey, here is where I think you are going wrong:

**Change this part:**

```
$block->getContent()->setAttributes(array(
  'contentRss' => array($entry->id)
));
```

**To this:**

```
$block->getContent()->contentRss = array($entry->id);
```

Comment: No worries, did it work?

Comment: Excellent! In which case could you mark this answer as correct to better help out other people?