# How can I add a dynamic number of rows to a matrix via plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, matrix

I would like to have a front-end profile form on my website that contains a matrix field. The matrix field will allow the user to add an infinite number of awards they have earned. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few threads on this that I found helpful. I think they are all worth looking at and reading through as my solution may vary based on your needs.

- [Save matrix block to new entry in plugin](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10371/save-matrix-block-to-new-entry-in-plugin)
- [How to save a matrix content of a new entry in my plugin?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1101/how-to-save-a-matrix-content-of-a-new-entry-in-my-plugin)
- [Saving new Matrix data](https://gist.github.com/brandonkelly/8149062)

Here is the complete solution that ended up working. If there are improvements, please let me know so I can update the thread accordingly!

**twig**

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

    {{ getCsrfInput() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="profile/saveProfile">

    ...

    {% if profile.awardsHonors|length %}
        <div id="awards">
            {% for block in profile.awardsHonors %}
                <div class="matrixblock award">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="hidden" name="fields[awardsHonors][{{ block.id }}][type]" value="award">
                        <input type="hidden" name="fields[awardsHonors][{{ block.id }}][enabled]" value="1">

                        <input type="text" name="fields[awardsHonors][{{ block.id }}][fields][award]" class="form-control" value="{{ block.award }}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% set blockId = block.id %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% else %}
        <div id="awards"></div>
    {% endif %}

    ...

    <button type="button" id="addAward">Add Award</button>

    ...
</form>
```

**javascript**

```
var awardBlockNum = 1;

$('#addAward').click(function (event) {
    var markup = '<div class="matrixblock award">' +
        '<div class="form-group">' +
        '<input type="hidden" name="fields[awardsHonors][new' + awardBlockNum + '][type]" value="award">' +
        '<input type="hidden" name="fields[awardsHonors][new' + awardBlockNum + '][enabled]" value="1">' +
        '<input type="text" name="fields[awardsHonors][new' + awardBlockNum + '][fields][award]" class="form-control">' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>';

        $(markup).appendTo($('#awards'));

        awardBlockNum++;
    });
```

**MyPluginController**

```
public function actionSaveProfile()
{
    $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
    $criteria->section = 'mySectionHandle';
    $criteria->limit = 1;
    $criteria->status = null;
    $criteria->authorId = craft()->request->getPost('userId');

    $entries = $criteria->find();

    if ($entries) {
        foreach ($criteria as $entry) {
            $awardMatrixData = array();

            /**
             * New matrix fields are prefixed with 'new1'.
             * To compensate we need to create a new increment variable to correctly store the matrix number
             * while looping the correct amount of times.
             */

            foreach (craft()->request->getPost('fields.awardsHonors') as $key => $value) {
                $i = 1;

                if ($key == 'new' . $i) { // Check for a new award.
                    $awardMatrixData['new' . $i] = array(
                        'type' => 'award',
                        'enabled' => true,
                        'fields' => array(
                            'award' => craft()->request->getPost('fields.awardsHonors.new' . $i . '.fields.award')
                        )
                    );
                } else { // Update existing awards.
                    $awardMatrixData[$key] = array(
                        'type' => 'award',
                        'enabled' => true,
                        'fields' => array(
                            'award' => craft()->request->getPost('fields.awardsHonors.' . $key . '.fields.award')
                        )
                    );
                }

                $i++;
            }

            $entry->setContentFromPost(array(
                ...
                ...
                'awardsHonors' => $matrixData
            ));

            if (craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry)) {
                // Profile updated!;
            } else {
                // Could not save entry (profile).
            }
        }
    } else {
        // No entry found that matches criteria.
    }
}
```